# ArityException when calling count for lazy sequence

Tags: clojure

I have written the following function for determining if two strings differ by exactly `differing-char-no` character positions.

```
(defn differ-by
    [id1 id2 differing-char-no]
    (let [zipped-ids (map vector (seq id1) (seq id2))
          differing-char-positions (filter #(not= %1 %2) zipped-ids)]
        (= differing-char-no (count differing-char-positions))))
```

The function, however, produces an `ArityException` when called. The exception is from the `count` function call, and says `Wrong number of args (1) passed to: ...`.

By debugging the code I observed that both `differing-char-positions` and `zipped-ids` are lazy sequences which have not been realized. However, evaluating `(count zipped-ids)` works fine right away, but `(count differring-char-positions)` only works after having called `(count zipped-ids)` once, i.e. after `zipped-ids` has been realized. Could someone explain this behaviour? Why do these lazy sequences behave differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zipped-ids` produces a sequence of vectors, so the filter function must accept a single parameter:

`(filter (fn [[a b]] (not= a b)) (map vector (seq [1 2 3]) (seq '(:a :b :c))))`

But there is a better way:

`(filter (partial apply not=) (map vector (seq [1 2 3]) (seq '(1 :b :c))))`

Comment: I see. So the problem was in that part afterall. Thank you for the response!